# Pub install failed, [1] Class '_File' has no instance method 'readAsStringSync' with matching arguments

Tags: dart

I recently did an update to Dart M3 (20602) and now i have a problem with pubspec.yaml.
When i try to install packages i receive this message error :

> Pub install failed, [1] Class '_File' has no instance method 'readAsStringSync' with matching arguments.

Any workaround is appreciate, thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post the contents of pubspec.yaml?

Comment: Hi Shailen, it is the one of MVC example in Dart, asap if necessary I will post it.

Comment: Thank You Shailen, this is my pubspec.yaml :
"name: todomvc
description: TodoMVC built with the Dart Web UI package
dependencies:
  browser: any
  web_ui: any"

Comment: My host is a Win7 64bit and my Java version is : 1.6.0.22

Comment: --- 2-apr-2013 22.29.42 Running pub install ... ---
Pub install failed, [1] Class '_File' has no instance method 'readAsStringSync' with matching arguments.

NoSuchMethodError: incorrect number of arguments passed to method named 'readAsStringSync'
Receiver: Instance of '_File@0x1da10ec4'
Tried calling: readAsStringSync(encoding: Instance of 'Encoding')
Found: readAsStringSync(encoding)

Comment: Hi Shailen, I have solved.
The issue was at line 44 of "..\dart-sdk\util\pub\io.dart"
I've changed the parameter of the function from "encoding: Encoding.UTF_8" to "Encoding.UTF_8" and seems to me work fine now. Thank You for your attention.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.